# Constructing list of lists inside list comprehensions in Haskell

Tags: algorithm, haskell, pattern-matching

There's an algorithm I've found on wiki.haskell.org for generating combinations of n elements from a given list. It constructs `[[a]]` via list comprehension.

```
combos :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
combos 0 _  = [ [] ]
combos n xs = [ y:ys | y:xs' <- tails xs
                           , ys <- combos (n-1) xs']
```

Say we execute `combos 2 [1,2,3]`, then the main function would look like:

```
combos 2 [1,2,3] = [ y:ys | y:xs' <- [[1,2,3],[2,3],[3],[]]
                           , ys <- combos 1 xs']
```

I assume that in a pattern `y:xs'` `y` is a list (`[1,2,3]` for the first run) and `xs'` is a list of lists (`[[2,3],[3],[]]` for the first run).

I'm confused about the part, when `xs'` gets thrown as an argument to the recursive `combos` call (`ys <- combos 1 xs')`. (`combos` now becomes `[[a]] -> [[[a]]]`?)

How it is all working out? Could you, please, describe how this function works?

Answer (score 3):

Note the difference between `… <- …` and `let … = …` here. In a list comprehension, both sides of `x <- xs` can’t have the same type; `x` is successively assigned to each *element* of `xs`.

In your example, `(y:xs') <- [[1,2,3],[2,3],[3],[]]` means we *take* elements from that list matching the pattern `(y:xs')`. So the first time we make a selection here, `y == 1` and `xs' == [2,3]`; the second time we make a selection, `y == 2` and `xs' == [3]`, et cetera.

Comment: considering `(y:xs') <- [[1,2,3],[2,3],[3],[]]` (1), the function should take the fist element and construct all combinations starting from it; then take the second element etc...  so, what happens when the pattern (1) reaches `[3]` ?

Comment: @ibe, `[3] = 3 : []`  . So `y` will be `3` and `xs'` will be `[]`.  Figure out what `combos` does on an empty list and you will know...   (Btw `[ whatever | x <- [] ]` is just `[]`, because there's no value we could give `x`)

Comment: @luqui `y` will be `3` and `xs'` will be `[]`. then given `ys <- combos 1 []` won't we have `3:[]` ? by algorithm we construct combinations by taking 1st element and generating all combos starting from it etc..., this goes to the `end` of the list. however there aren't any combos starting from `3`. how the function handles it?

Comment: `combos 1 [] = []`, so `ys` can't be assigned any value, thus the whole list comprehension is `[]`.  Again this is about the difference between `<-` and `let`.  When you say `x <- xs`, `x` takes on *each* value in `xs`, like a loop.

Comment: @luqui btw, how it is possible for `combos` to return `[]` when by type signature it returns `[[]]` ? is haskell somehow relaxes this or what?

Comment: `[[a]]` means `a list of lists of a`; the outer list can be empty, too!